# Compact C# source code by removing everything that's not syntactically necessary?

Tags: c#, minify

For coding challenges with source code size limits it would be nice to have a way of removing everything that's not syntactically necessary - like most white space and comments - from a piece of code before submitting it. For seriously serious challenges some more transformations might be desirable, like balancing usings vs. explicit qualifications, or renaming symbols the way source code obfuscators work.

Is there a way of abusing the of Visual Studio editor - or the .NET runtime - to accomplish such source code compaction?

Note: this is for automated sites that use robot judges and where submissions are not visible to other contestants. Usually the source code size limits are intended to keep people from hard-coding huge tables instead of coding an algorithmic solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio 2015 you can do this pretty easily with a [live code analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx) and a [Code Fix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn904670.aspx). Just remove most things that is a "Trivia" type (for example you don't remove the first whitespace in `int x = 123;` but you could check that the whitepsace is only one character long), it should still compile but be the absolutely smallest the code can be.